# ArrayFormula works only on the first row with Indirect()

Tags: google-sheets

The objective is to apply a calculation `(Y4:Y-(W4:W*V4:V))+S4:S-T4:T)` to a column's cells, and leave `0` where the `V` cell in the respected row is `blank` or `0`. **Note:** The calculation itself doesn't matter.

When the first row's `V` column is `0` or `blank`, the formula below just applies `0` on the first affected row, but the rest of the column remains blank.

However, if the condition which checks `V` cell returns `FALSE` for the first row (meaning the `V` cell in the respected row has a non-zero amount), the whole column gets the appropriate calculation result applied in each row.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
        OR(
            ISBLANK(INDIRECT("V" & ROW())),
            EQ(INDIRECT("V" & ROW()), 0)
        ),
        0,
        (Y4:Y-(W4:W*V4:V))+S4:S-T4:T
    )
)
```

How to amend the formula so that the rest of the column gets filled even when the first row's condition evaluates the `V` cell to be `0` or `blank`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your formula:

1. You cannot use an aggregate function like `OR` inside an
   `arrayformula`. This is described here
   https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/dl_9H6hFwaE.
2. Testing for `0` or `blank` can be done with one logical expression like
   `C1=0` or `EQ(C1,0)` , both of which will return true if `C1` is
   either 0 or blank.  (Note that this makes it hard to test if a cell
   contains 0, but does not contain blank). See here https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/214244/xl-how-to-create-a-formula-to-correctly-evaluate-blank-cells

I don't know why you are using INDIRECT, but this formula should work as you need:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if( eq(V4:V,0),0, (Y4:Y-(W4:W*V4:V))+S4:S-T4:T))
```

We have removed the logical OR (which kills the arrayformula).

We have removed the redundant test for blank and 0;

Comment: It worked. Thanks for breaking down the reason of failure and the improvement note for checking `blank` and `0` cells. As for using `INDIRCET`, I was thinking It should get utilized to address the respected cells in the same row, even in `ArrayFormula`. Now that I removed the `INDIRECT`, I got rid of the rest of columns filled by zeros where the previous columns used in the formula hadn't had an amount. After all, Why `INDIRECT` generates all those `0` in the rest cells of the column?

Comment: About using aggregating functions in `ArrayFormula` Why this works on the same sheet whereas it has `AND`? `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(S4:S),ISBLANK(V4:V)),S4:S-T4:T,Z4:Z+(S4:S-T4:T)))`

Comment: Honestly I don't know `AND` why it works in this situation. It might be just lucky circumstances. The best advice I can give is if the documentation gives a list of aggregation formulas that won't work reliably (maybe `undefined behaviour`)  with `ARRAYFORMULA`, then best not to do it, and instead use the workaround provided. `undefined behavior' is a concept in all computer languages and you can look it up.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration.